# How to determine the type of Object in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class (A) which contains other classes B,C,D as variables . At any point of time class A will either have B,C,D populated in it.

How can we use streams/map to determine the kind of object present and return it to caller ?

Comment: You mean `getClass()`?

Comment: you could make the variables `Optional` and check with `isPresent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class A {

    public static class B {}
    public static class C {}
    public static class D {}
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    
    public A(B b, C c, D d) {
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public Class<?> getValueType() {
        A me=this;
        try {
            return Arrays.stream(this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()).filter(field->{
                try {
                    return field.get(me)!=null;
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }).findAny().get().get(me).getClass();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(new A(new B(),null,null).getValueType());
        System.out.println(new A(null,new C(),null).getValueType());
        System.out.println(new A(null,null,new D()).getValueType());
    }
}
```

Comment: Very decent answer!

Comment: Or `return Stream.of(b, c, d).filter(Object::nonNull) …`

Answer (score 1):

use `reflect` to get all fields and then do want you want

```java
public class A {
    private Integer a;
    private String b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aobject = new A();
        Field[] fields = A.class.getDeclaredFields();
        Arrays.stream(fields).map(Field::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```